# WCF Service JSON Data

Tags: wcf, json, format, return

I've created a WCF Web Service which returns data in JSON format. The code for the service is as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<MyCustomer> GetCustomerJSON();
```

And

```
public List<MyCustomer> GetCustomerJSON()
    {
        var nm = (from n in _ent.Customers
                  select new MyCustomer() { CustomerID = n.CustomerID, AccountNumber = n.AccountNumber }).Take(10);

        return nm.ToList();

    }
```

However, the output isn't well formed. It included square brackets at start and end. 
Because of which I can't use Json Parser tool.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you return `List<T>` it will be encoded like array of `T` in the JSON and array will be encoded with respect of square brackets:

```
[{"strProprety":"bla","intProperty":123,"booleanProperty":true}]
```

In your case it will be probably

```
[{"CustomerID":1,"AccountNumber":123},{"CustomerID":2,"AccountNumber":456}]
```

It is valid JSON. You can use http://www.jsonlint.com/ to verify this. So WCF produce correct output and you have problem only with the "Json Parser tool".